# $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<1$ then $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers and $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<1$. If $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}\sum a_nx^n=A$, prove that $\sum a_n$ converges to $A$.

My attempt: given $\epsilon>0$, we can find $\delta$ such that if $x \in (1-\delta,1)$ then $|\sum a_nx^n-A| < \epsilon$. Now consider $|\sum a_n - A| \leq |\sum a_n - \sum a_nx^n| + |\sum a_nx^n-A|$ and since $x^n \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 1^-$, we have $|\sum a_n - \sum a_nx^n| \rightarrow 0$ and so $\sum a_n$ converges to $A$. Is my proof valid? Thanks.

Edit: As suggested by @Clement C., my notes also say that by Tauberian theorem if we prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}na_n=0$ then we can conclude the statement. I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: You should be Abel to prove that.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Abels theorem?

Comment: But as far as I know, Abel's theorem's assumption is that $\sum a_n$ converges. This problem is quite the opposite. (See Rudin Thm 8.2)

Comment: the result can't be true if ${a_n}$ is real only for example $a_n=(-1)^n$ but if ${a_n}$ is non negative i don't know, but  i think it will use absolute convergence

Comment: What is your argument for $$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \Biggl\lvert \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\Biggr\rvert = 0\,?$$

Comment: The best proof of this would be using Beppo Levi's theorem.

Comment: @Lewis That would be a [Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_tauberian_theorems#Tauberian_theorems), then. But for non-negative series, and therefore without the assumption $a_n=o(1/n)$.

Comment: Hmmm...But the answer in the other question didn't explain very clearly why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n \leq A$ though.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That was the part where I am most unsure of. I just found on my notes that if we can prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}na_n=0$ then we can directly show the claim by Tauberian theorem as suggested by Clement.

Comment: @Lewis You have $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, so $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence. Since $0\leq \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \leq A$ for all $N$, it is a non-decreasing *bounded* sequence. Therefore it converges by the monotone convergence theorem, and its limit (when $N\to\infty$) satisfies $0\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \leq A$.

Comment: This looks like an early exercise from Conway's Complex Analysis textbook. Can you use any analyticity results?

Comment: @Lewis The proof given by Winther is very clear her use the positivity of $(a_n)$ to say that for all $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \leq A$ which give the answer

Comment: @enthdegree: This is an exercise from my real analysis class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = B \in [0, \infty]$. 
Of course $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$, so 
we must have $B \ge A$.

On the other hand, suppose $B > A$.  Take $C_1, C_2$ so $B > C_1 > C_2 > A$.  There must be
$N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \ge C_1$.  Take $r \in (0,1)$ so $r^N > C_2/C_1$.
Then if $r < x < 1$ we have $$A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n \ge \sum_{n=1}^N a_n (C_2/C_1) \ge C_2 > A$$
contradiction.